# Validation rules not working : Yii

Tags: php, yii

I have two fields in my webapp, and have given validation rules to make it mandatory. But when I submit my form, it is getting submitted even if the fields are empty.

model:

```
public function rules()
{
return array(
array('fname, mobile, address', 'required'),
array('econtact, mobile', 'length', 'max'=>10),
array('fname', 'length', 'max'=>40),
array('lname', 'length', 'max'=>25),
    array('subject, body', 'required'),
array('filename', 'file', 'types'=>'jpg, gif, png,pdf'),
}
```

controller:

```
public function actionEmail()
{
$model=new Contactlist;
if(isset($_POST['Contactlist']))
{
$model->attributes=$_POST['Contactlist'];
if($model->validate())
{
require("class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PhpMailer;
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = true;
$mail->Username = 'from@gmail.com';
$mail->Port = '465';
$mail->Password = '****';
$mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;
$mail->Mailer = "smtp";
$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;
$mail->SetFrom('frm@gmail.com','from');
$mail->Subject = $_POST['Contactlist']['subject'];
$mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!';
$mail->MsgHTML($_POST['Contactlist']['body']);
$mail->Send();
}}}
```

None of the validation rules specified are working. I tried echoing text in rules() method of model. This is working fine which means that "$model->validate()" is redirecting it to rules() method only. But I don't understand whats going wrong here

Comment: show your full model and your full actionEmail and view.

Comment: How do you dilplay errors? maybe they just doesn't dilplay

Comment: I have edited, plz have a look at it. Thanks

Comment: hum maybe try to set allowEmpty to false in the length rules

Comment: It may be a small thing but why do you have two 'required' rules. merge them all into a single rule? e.g. `array('fname, mobile, address, subject, body', 'required'),`

Comment: use $model->errors to check the errors

Answer (score 0):

there if you can please add  scenario for the model object in your controller where you create object of the model

Instead

```
$model=new Contactlist;
```

write

```
 $model=new Contactlist('contactus');
```

then come  to your model and add scenario for the required rule

```
array('fname, mobile, address', 'required','on'=>'contactus'),
```

after this all please **remove your last required rule** or add any one of them otherwise you have to create new scenario for that.

that's it if not working message me.